# QPlainTextEdit::toPlainText() but include newline characters from word wrap

Tags: c++, qt, qplaintextedit

I have a `QPlainTextEdit` that contains some text. Word wrap is enabled.

When I retrieve the text with `toPlainText()` the resulting string does not contain the newline characters created from word wrap. This is because those newline characters weren't directly entered by the user.

I would like to retain those newline characters that word wrap created. How does one do this?

For example:

Add `QPlainTextEdit` widget to the window and fill it with enough text for word wrap to create new lines.

[image]

Output that text to file:

```
QString myText = ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText();

QFile outputFile("test.txt");
outputFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
outputFile.write(myText.toUtf8());
outputFile.close();
```

The resulting output is just 1 line.
[image]

How can I retain the newline characters word wrap simulates?

Comment: please, provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc I have edited my post

Comment: What do you need the line breaks for?

Comment: It's complicated... but i definitely need them

Comment: You probably need to do this yourself. You need QFontMerics, and font used and line width in pixels from your QPlainTextEdit.

Comment: Did you wrote the single line in QPlainTextEdit? if you want to 
 output multi-line, then using Enter key. _does not contain the newline characters_. Have you checked the return of `toPlainText()`?

Comment: Yes it's a single line written without the use of the Enter key. But I want the output string to contain all newline characters that word wrap simulates.

Answer (score 1):

I make offer use of `QTextEdit` instead of `QPlainTextEdit`, because its easy to access what you want (It does work) :

- Drag a `QTextEdit` control on widget
- Select it, and change `lineWrapMode` option to `FixedColumnWidth` (in properties section)
- Then, set `lineWrapColumnOrWidth` option to (your arbitrary line length when wrapped e.g. 10)
- Now fill `QTextEdit`, So you can see what you expected!

Now try this for get `QTextEdit` data line by line (`"textEdit"` is as `QTextEdit`) :

```
// QTextEdit content
QString strLines = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();

// line count of QTextEdit
int lineCount = strLines.length() / ui->textEdit->lineWrapColumnOrWidth();
int lineLength = ui->textEdit->lineWrapColumnOrWidth();

for(int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {

    QMessageBox::information(this, "", strLines.mid(i * lineLength, lineLength));
}
```

And for splitting real `\n` You can try :

```
QString.split(QRegExp("[\r\n]"),QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

This statement splits the string whenever any of the **newline** character.

Comment: Wouldn't this cut off words right in the middle though? Word wrap keeps entire words together when it moves to a new line. I need the newline characters that exist between words, not just character count.

Comment: @mrg95 I edited my answer, attention about last sentences i appended in my answer